# I am not sure why python kept giving the error message of 'price is not defined'

Tags: python, nameerror

My main issue here is that I am unsure why the python kept returning the error of 'NameError: name 'price' is not defined'. The error occurred at line 53 'upsize1 = computeUpsizetea(upsize,price)'

(Side note: --> For the coding, can just ignore the part about "Problem ...")

Did I miss any code that was supposed to be in the coding itself?

I don't know how to actually defined the price.

I tried to change the price to value which was copied from line 32 ('def computeUpsizetea(upsize,value):') but then python will churn out another error 'NameError: name 'value' is not defined'.

By the way I just started learning how to use Python so I tried to find different type of solution that was on the web, but was still unable to solve. Can anyone help to guide me through, thanks a lot.

This is my code:

```js
# Create function to display menu
def showMenu():
    print("*---Standard size Bubble Tea----------------------------*") 
    print("1. Milk Tea                                         $3.80")
    print("2. Jasmine Green Tea                                $3.50")
    print("3. Red Plum Tea                                     $2.50")
    print("4. Earl Grey Milk Tea                               $5.30")
    print("5. Cranberry Fruit Tea                              $4.50")
    print("*-------------------------------------------------------*")
    print("Additional 35% for upsize to large cup")
    print("Additional 50 cents to add white pearl")
    print("Delivery is $4. If the order is more than $30, it is free")
    print("*-------------------------------------------------------*")

# Create function to get the price of customer order
def getPrice(item):
    if item =="1" :
        return 3.80
    elif item =="2" :
        return 3.50
    elif item == "3" :
        return 2.50
    elif item == "4" :
        return 5.30
    elif item == "5" :
        return 4.50
    else:
        print("Incorrect item, please select again!")
        return 0
        
# Create function to compute upsize tea
def computeUpsizetea(upsize,value):
    if upsize.upper() == 'Y':
        extra = 0.35 * value
    else:
        extra = 0
    return extra
    
# Create function to compute adding of peal
def computeAddpeal(addpeal):
    if addpeal.upper() == 'Y':
        pealextra = 0.5
    else:
        pealextra = 0
    return pealextra

showMenu()
cusOrder = input("Select your tea:")
upsize = input("Upsize to large cup? (Y/N):")
addpeal = input("Add peals? (Y/N):")
orderQty = float(input("Enter your order quantity:"))
    
upsize1 = computeUpsizetea(upsize,price)
addpeal1 = computeAddpeal(addpeal)
totalupsize = price + upsize1
totalpeal = totalupsize + addpeal1
purchaseAmt = totalpeal * orderQty

# Create function to compute delivery fee
def deliveryFee(purchaseAmt):
    if purchaseAmt > 30:
        deliver = 0
    else:
        deliver = 4
    return deliver

totaldeliver = deliveryFee(purchaseAmt)
deliverycharge = totaldeliver + purchaseAmt

#Create next item
print("Total Sales: $", format(purchaseAmt,'.2f'))

#Problem 3: How to loop this part where by can return back to the selection part?
nextItem1 = input("Next item? (Y/N):")
for nextItem in nextItem1:
    if nextItem1.upper() == "Y":
        next(showMenu())
else:
    print("Delivery Fee: $", format(totaldeliver,'.2f'))
    print("Please pay: $", format(deliverycharge,'.2f'))
```

Comment: You first passed `price` in `upsize1` but it is not defined before that.

Answer (score 1):

```
upsize1 = computeUpsizetea(upsize,price)
```

This is showing error because you have not initialized the price variable;

Use this:

```py
price = int(input("Enter price "))
```

or use your custom price

whole code:

```py
# Create function to display menu
def showMenu():
    print("*---Standard size Bubble Tea----------------------------*") 
    print("1. Milk Tea                                         $3.80")
    print("2. Jasmine Green Tea                                $3.50")
    print("3. Red Plum Tea                                     $2.50")
    print("4. Earl Grey Milk Tea                               $5.30")
    print("5. Cranberry Fruit Tea                              $4.50")
    print("*-------------------------------------------------------*")
    print("Additional 35% for upsize to large cup")
    print("Additional 50 cents to add white pearl")
    print("Delivery is $4. If the order is more than $30, it is free")
    print("*-------------------------------------------------------*")

# Create function to get the price of customer order
def getPrice(item):
    if item =="1" :
        return 3.80
    elif item =="2" :
        return 3.50
    elif item == "3" :
        return 2.50
    elif item == "4" :
        return 5.30
    elif item == "5" :
        return 4.50
    else:
        print("Incorrect item, please select again!")
        return 0
        
# Create function to compute upsize tea
def computeUpsizetea(upsize,value):
    if upsize.upper() == 'Y':
        extra = 0.35 * value
    else:
        extra = 0
    return extra
    
# Create function to compute adding of peal
def computeAddpeal(addpeal):
    if addpeal.upper() == 'Y':
        pealextra = 0.5
    else:
        pealextra = 0
    return pealextra

showMenu()
cusOrder = input("Select your tea:")
upsize = input("Upsize to large cup? (Y/N):")
addpeal = input("Add peals? (Y/N):")
orderQty = float(input("Enter your order quantity:"))
price = int(input("Enter price "))
    
upsize1 = computeUpsizetea(upsize,price)
addpeal1 = computeAddpeal(addpeal)
totalupsize = price + upsize1
totalpeal = totalupsize + addpeal1
purchaseAmt = totalpeal * orderQty

# Create function to compute delivery fee
def deliveryFee(purchaseAmt):
    if purchaseAmt > 30:
        deliver = 0
    else:
        deliver = 4
    return deliver

totaldeliver = deliveryFee(purchaseAmt)
deliverycharge = totaldeliver + purchaseAmt

#Create next item
print("Total Sales: $", format(purchaseAmt,'.2f'))

#Problem 3: How to loop this part where by can return back to the selection part?
nextItem1 = input("Next item? (Y/N):")
for nextItem in nextItem1:
    if nextItem1.upper() == "Y":
        next(showMenu())
else:
    print("Delivery Fee: $", format(totaldeliver,'.2f'))
    print("Please pay: $", format(deliverycharge,'.2f'))
```